# Understanding the Quotient norm, constructed example

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

I just read the definition of the quotient norm, but it had no examples, so I constructed my own. Is this correct?

Let $(X=\Bbb R^3,\|\cdot\|)$ with Euclidean norm and $Y\subset X$, $\quad Y=\{(a,0,0):a\in \Bbb R\}$

So $X/Y = \{ [(a,b,c)]=(a,b,c)+Y: a,b,c\in \Bbb R\}$

And we look at: $$\|[(3,6,4)]\|_{X/Y}= \|(3,6,4)-(a,0,0)\|_X$$
$$=\inf_{y\in Y}\left(\sqrt{(3-a)^2+6^2+4^2}\right)=\sqrt{(3-3)^2+6^2+4^2}=\sqrt{36+16}=\sqrt{52}=2\sqrt{13}$$

Is that the correct way to apply the quotient norm?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: wunderbar @RaziehNoori!